# Check for mutability in Python?

Tags: python, immutability, hashable

Consider this [code](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.copy):

```
a = {...} # a is an dict with arbitrary contents
b = a.copy()
```

1. What role does mutability play in the keys and values of the dicts?
2. How do I ensure changes to keys or values of one dict are not reflected in the other?
3. How does this relate to the hashable [constraint](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) of the dict keys?
4. Are there any differences in behaviour between Python 2.x and Python 3.x?

**How do I check if a type is mutable in Python?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Keys **must be hashable** - that's all that's forced upon you. In particular, *you can have a user-defined class whose instances are hashable but also mutable* - but *this is generally a bad idea*.
2. By not sharing values between the two dicts. It's generally OK to share the keys, because they should be mutable (and will be, for built-in types). Copying the dictionary, in the sense of the `copy` standard library module, is definitely safe. Calling the dict constructor here works, too: `b = dict(a)`. You could also use immutable values.
3. All built-in immutable types are hashable. All built-in mutable types are not hashable. The constraint on dict keys simply requires that the built-in `hash` function works on the key, which in turn requires that its class implements the `__hash__` magic method.

   **However, the code may break subtly or unexpectedly** if an object's hash could ever change during its lifetime. For a pathological example:

   ```
   >>> import random
   >>> class x:
   ...     def __hash__(self): return random.randint(0, 100)
   ... 
   >>> a, b = x(), x()
   >>> c = {a:1, b:2}
   >>> c[a]
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   KeyError: <__main__.x object at ...>
   ```

   This is why trying to make a mutable, hashable type is ill-advised: the hash is expected not to change, but is also expected to reflect the state of the object.
4. No.

A type is mutable if it is not immutable. A type is immutable if it is a built-in immutable type: `str`, `int`, `long`, `bool`, `float`, `tuple`, and probably a couple others I'm forgetting. User-defined types are always mutable.

An object is mutable if it is not immutable. An object is immutable if it consists, recursively, of only immutable-typed sub-objects. Thus, a tuple of lists is mutable; you cannot replace the elements of the tuple, but you can modify them through the list interface, changing the overall data.

Comment: Re immutable objects: "Objects whose value can change are said to be mutable; objects whose value is unchangeable once they are created are called immutable. (The value of an immutable container object that contains a reference to a mutable object can change when the latter’s value is changed; however the container is still considered immutable, because the collection of objects it contains cannot be changed. So, immutability is not strictly the same as having an unchangeable value, it is more subtle.)"  http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types

Comment: And further: "An object’s mutability is determined by its type; for instance, numbers, strings and tuples are immutable, while dictionaries and lists are mutable."

Comment: Fair enough. I appear to be conflating the Python-standard definition with the logical definition. :)

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Can you provide a test for immutability?

Comment: @Matt: I already explained that this is impossible--the concept doesn't exist programmatically in Python and there's no way to test for it.

Comment: Furthermore, you **don't care** because it's hashability, not immutability, that matters for dicts; and because reference semantics are reference semantics, and work the same way whether or not there exists an interface for mutation.

Comment: User-defined types are not always mutable. Declaring, for example, `class mytuple(tuple): pass` creates an immutable user-defined type.

Comment: it wasn't mentioned, but all instances of user-defined types are hashable on default, https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html

Comment: Are functions mutable? `def f(): pass`, `f.a = 42`.

Comment: Yes, functions are objects, and those objects are mutable as you've demonstrated to yourself. What isn't mutable (last I checked; mutating it sounds like a really bad idea anyway!) is the underlying compiled bytecode object representing the function's code (hidden behind a couple layers of scarily-named attributes).

Comment: <Sigh>. I too was hoping to find something similar to the [`callable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#callable) built-in that returns `True` if the argument is a mutable object, `False` otherwise.

Comment: @martineau As explained in Glenn Maynard's answer, it doesn't really exist in the language level in the first place. The distinction is more between mutating and non-mutating functionality; immutability is simply the absence of mutating functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I get that. My use case is not one of the usual reasons for wanting to know this — to be specific it's about whether a copy should be made of something that would otherwise result in its value being shared (i.e. to prevent it from being uses as the default value of an argument).

Answer (score 17):

There isn't actually any such thing as mutability or immutability at the language level in Python.  Some objects provide no way to change them (eg. strings and tuples), and so are *effectively* immutable, but it's purely conceptual; there's no property at the language level indicating this, neither to your code nor to Python itself.

Immutability is not actually relevant to dicts; it's perfectly fine to use mutable values as keys.  What matters is comparison and hashing: the object must always remain equal to itself.  For example:

```
class example(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.value = a
    def __eq__(self, rhs):
        return self.value == rhs.value
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)

a = example(1)
d = {a: "first"}
a.data = 2
print d[example(1)]
```

Here, `example` is *not* immutable; we're modifying it with `a.data = 2`.  Yet, we're using it as a key of a hash without any trouble.  Why?  The property we're changing has no effect on equality: the hash is unchanged, and `example(1)` is always equal to `example(1)`, ignoring any other properties.

The most common use of this is caching and memoization: having a property cached or not doesn't logically change the object, and usually has no effect on equality.

(I'm going to stop here--please don't ask five questions at once.)

Comment: The first 4 questions are the context in which I'm asking the final question.

Answer (score 8):

There are MutableSequence, MutableSet, MutableMapping in module [collections](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html). Which can be used to check mutability of premade types.

```
issubclass(TYPE, (MutableSequence, MutableSet, MutableMapping))
```

If you want use this on user defined types, the type must be either inherited from one of them or registered as a virtual subclass.

```
class x(MutableSequence):
    ...
```

or

```
class x:
    ...

abc.ABCMeta.register(MutableSequence,x)
```

Comment: Note all user defined classes are mutable by default.

Answer (score 4):

There's really no *guarantee* that a type which is hashable is also immutable, but at very least, correctly implementing `__hash__` requires that the type is immutable, with respect to its own hash, and to equality.  This is not enforced in any particular way.

However, we are all adults.  It would be unwise to implement `__hash__` unless you really meant it.  Roughly speaking, this just boils down to saying that if a type actually can be used as a dictionary key, then it is intended to be used in that way.

If you're looking for something that is *like* a dict, but also immutable, then [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) might be your best bet from what's in the standard library.  Admittedly it's not a very good approximation, but it's a start.

Comment: cPython goes to some pretty amazing lengths to cover it's behind in case a dict key really isn't immutable.  The worst that can happen is that `__getitem__` and family do not return the expected key, because it is in the wrong bucket.

Comment: Implementing `__hash__` has nothing to do with whether it's intended to be used as a key for anything, and it's perfectly normal to implement it for mutable types--in fact, you get a default `__hash__` of `id(self)` for every user-defined type.  Using an object as a key adds the requirement that the hash not change, but that's strictly dict's requirement; it has no bearing on `__dict__` in general.  Dicts are a *user* of `__hash__`; they do not *define* it.

Comment: exactly what is the point of `__hash__` except to use it in hash maps?

Comment: Hashes have many uses.  If it wasn't intended to be of general use, Python wouldn't have a builtin named `hash`.

Comment: Yes, Ok, can you make a suggestion?

Comment: I'm with @TokenMacGuy. Where else is `hash` used?

Answer (score 2):

1. dict **keys** must be hashable, which implies they have an immutable *hash* value.  dict **values** may or may not be mutable; however, if they are mutable this impacts your second question.
2. "Changes to the keys" will not be reflected between the two dicts.  Changes to immutable values, such as strings will also not be reflected.  Changes to mutable objects, such as user defined classes will be reflected because the object is stored by id (i.e. reference).

   ```
   class T(object):
     def __init__(self, v):
       self.v = v


   t1 = T(5)


   d1 = {'a': t1}
   d2 = d1.copy()


   d2['a'].v = 7
   d1['a'].v   # = 7


   d2['a'] = T(2)
   d2['a'].v   # = 2
   d1['a'].v   # = 7


   import copy
   d3 = copy.deepcopy(d2) # perform a "deep copy"
   d3['a'].v = 12
   d3['a'].v   # = 12
   d2['a'].v   # = 2
   ```
3. I think this is explained by the first two answers.
4. Not that I know of in this respect.

**some additional thoughts**:

There are two main things to know for understanding the behavior of *keys*: keys must be [hashable](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-hashable) (which means they implement [`object.__hash__(self)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__)) and they must also be "comparable" (which means they implement something like [`object.__cmp__(self)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)).  One important take-away from the docs: by default, user-defined objects' hash functions return [`id()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id).

Consider this example:

```
class K(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
     self.x = x
     self.y = y
  def __hash__(self):
     return self.x + self.y

k1 = K(1, 2)
d1 = {k1: 3}
d1[k1] # outputs 3
k1.x = 5
d1[k1] # KeyError!  The key's hash has changed!
k2 = K(2, 1)
d1[k2] # KeyError!  The key's hash is right, but the keys aren't equal.
k1.x = 1
d1[k1] # outputs 3

class NewK(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
     self.x = x
     self.y = y
  def __hash__(self):
     return self.x + self.y
  def __cmp__(self, other):
     return self.x - other.x

nk1 = NewK(3, 4)
nd1 = {nk1: 5}
nd1[nk1] # outputs 5
nk2 = NewK(3, 7)
nk1 == nk2 # True!
nd1[nk2] # KeyError! The keys' hashes differ.
hash(nk1) == hash(nk2) # False
nk2.y = 4
nd1[nk2] # outputs 5

# Where this can cause issues:
nd1.keys()[0].x = 5
nd1[nk1] # KeyError! nk1 is no longer in the dict!
id(nd1.keys()[0]) == id(nk1)  # Yikes. True?!
nd1.keys()[0].x = 3
nd1[nk1]  # outputs 5
id(nd1.keys()[0]) == id(nk1)  # True!
```

*Values* are much easier to understand, the dict stores references to objects.  Read the sections on hashable.  Things like strings are immutable, if you "change" them, the dict you changed it in now references a new object.  Objects which are mutable can be "changed in-place", hence the value of both dicts will change.

```
d1 = {1: 'a'}
d2 = d1.copy()
id(d1[1]) == id(d2[1]) # True
d2[1] = 'z'
id(d1[1]) == id(d2[1]) # False

# the examples in section 2 above have more examples of this.
```

Anyway, here are the main points of all this:

- For *keys*, it may not be *mutability*, but rather *hashability and comparability*, that you care about.
- You care about mutability for values, because by definition, a mutable object's value can be changed without changing the reference to it.

I do not think there is a general way to test either of those points.  The tests for suitability would depend on your use-case.  For instance, it may be sufficient to check that an object does or does not implement `__hash__` and comparison (`__eq__` or `__cmp__`) functions.  Like-wise, you might be able to "check" an object's `__setattr__` method in some way to determine if it is mutable.

Comment: Can you explain why the deep copy is successful?

Comment: @Matt Joiner, it worked because of a very silly copy paste mistake.  It was not copying, but reassigning as in the example above it.  I corrected the example code.

Answer (score 1):

you can easily check if datatype is mutable or immutable by print an `id` or address of memory location of that datatype if datatype is immutable the address of memory location will change as you update the variable for example:

```
stn = 'Hello'
print(id(stn))
```

you will get address of memory location of that variable `stn` but when you concatenate that variable with some value and then go ahead `print` an address of memory location you will get different output from the first one likewise

```
stn += ' world'
print(id(stn))
```

for sure you will get another address of memory location from the first one but when you do it to mutable datatype an address of memory location will stay the same for example

```
lists = [1, 2, 3]
print(id(lists))
```

here you will get an address of memory location and also also if you go ahead and append some numbers to that `lists` an address of memory location will continue to be the same

```
lists.append(4)
print(id(lists))
```

and you have notice that an address of memory location is not the same to all computers
so you couldn't check the same datatype to different computers and get same result

Answer (score -3):

Dicts are unordered sets of key:value pairs. The keys must be immutable, and therefore hashable. To determine if an object is hashable, you can use the `hash()` function:

```
>>> hash(1)
1
>>> hash('a')
12416037344
>>> hash([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> hash((1,2,3))
2528502973977326415
>>> hash({1: 1})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

The values, on the other hand, can be any object. If you need to check if an object is immutable, then I would use `hash()`.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Mutable objects can be, and usually are, hashable.  Mutability and hashability are orthogonal concepts.

Comment: Is my assumption true for builtin types? Or is it just coincidence that the objects that my code test support my answer?

Comment: This looks fine to me. @GlennMaynard can you give some example where this does not work?

Comment: @rnbcoder: `class Foo(object): pass` `x = Foo()`. `x` is mutable but hashable.