# Why can't I use a list as a dict key in python? Exactly what can and cannot be used, and why?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, hashable

I found that the following are all valid:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[None] = 'foo'
>>> d[(1, 3)] = 'baz'
```

Even a module can be used as a dict key:

```
>>> import sys
>>> d[sys] = 'bar'
```

However, a list cannot, and neither can a tuple that contains a list:

```
>>> d[[2]] = 'spam'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> d[(1, [3])] = 'qux'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Why does storing a list inside the tuple mean it can't be a dict key any more? After all, I could just as easily "hide" a list inside a module (and indeed, e.g. `sys.path` is a list already).

I had some vague idea that that the key has to be "hashable" but I don't have a detailed understanding of what this means, or why there is such a limitation.  What would go wrong if Python allowed using lists as keys, say, using their memory location as the hash?

Comment: Related, but not closely enough to edit into the question: [Check for mutability in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374006)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There's a good article on the topic in the Python wiki: [Why Lists Can't Be Dictionary Keys](http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys). As explained there:

> What would go wrong if Python allowed using lists as keys, say, using their memory location as the hash?

It would cause some unexpected behavior. Lists are generally treated as if their value was derived from their content's values, for instance when checking (in-)equality. Many would - understandably - expect that you can use any list `[1, 2]` to get the same key, where you'd have to keep around exactly the same list object. But lookup by value breaks as soon as a list used as a key is modified, and lookup by identity requires keeping track of that exact list object - which isn't an ordinary requirement for working with lists.

Other objects, such as modules and `object`, make a much bigger deal out of their object identity anyway (when was the last time you had two distinct module objects called `sys`?), and are compared by that anyway. Therefore, it's less surprising - or even expected - that they, when used as dict keys, compare by identity in that case as well.

Answer (score 50):

**Why can't I use a list as a dict key in Python?**

```
>>> d = {repr([1,2,3]): 'value'}
{'[1, 2, 3]': 'value'}
```

As explained by others here, indeed you cannot. You can however use its string representation instead if you really want to use your list.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really see your point.  It's no different to using string literals as the keys.

Comment: True; I just saw so many answers actually explaining why you cannot use lists in terms of 'key must be hashable', which is so true, that I wanted to suggest a way around it, just in case somebody (new) will be looking for it...

Comment: Why not just convert the list to a tuple? Why convert it to a string? If you use a tuple, it'll work correctly with classes that have a custom comparison method `__eq__`. But if you convert them to strings, everything is compared by its string representation.

Comment: good point @Aran-Fey. Just make sure that any element in the tuple is itself hashable.  e.g. tuple([[1,2],[2,3]]) as a key will not work because the elements of the tuple are still lists.

Answer (score 46):

A list can be converted to a tuple, which can be used as a dict key: e.g.

```
d = {tuple([1,2,3]): 'value'}
```

Answer (score 23):

The issue is that tuples are immutable, and lists are not. Consider this example:

```
d = {}
li = [1,2,3]
d[li] = 5
li.append(4)
```

What should `d[li]` return? Is it the same list? How about `d[[1,2,3]]`? It has the same values, but is it a different list?

Ultimately, there is no satisfactory answer:

- If the only key that works is the original key, then it becomes impossible to access the value without retaining a reference to the original key (and having access to it)
- If only a key with equal contents works, then modifying the key changes how the lookup works; and any other code that has a reference to that list could modify it, possibly causing a surprise later.
- If both work, then you have very different keys are mapped to the same value, which is more than a little surprising.

Comment: Yes, it's the same list so I would expect `d[li]` to remain 5.  `d[[1,2,3]]` would refer to a different list object as the key, so it would be a KeyError.  I don't really see any problem yet.. except that letting a key get garbage collected might make some of the dict values inaccessible.  But that's a practical problem not a logical problem..

Comment: @wim: `d[list(li)]` being a KeyError is part of the problem. In nearly *every other use case*, `li` would be indistinguishable from a new list with identical contents. It works, but it's counter-intuitive to many. Plus, when was the last time you *really* has to use a list as dict key? The only use case I can imagine is when you're hashing everything by identity anyway, and in that case you should just do that instead of relying on `__hash__` and `__eq__` to be identity-based.

Comment: @delnan Is the _problem_ simply that it would be not very useful dict because of such complications? or is there some reason why it could actually break a dict?

Comment: @wim: The latter. As stated in my answer, it doesn't really break the requirements on dict keys, but it's likely to introduce more problems than it solves.

Comment: @wim I've updated my answer to include what I think is the biggest problem: lost keys. (In order to get the value, the original key must be present.)

Comment: @delnan - you meant to say 'the former'

Comment: @Jason: Yes, thanks for catching it (not that I could edit it, but anyway).

Comment: since dictionaries are mutable, for the same reason they cannot be used as keys.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an answer http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys

> What would go wrong if you tried to use lists as keys, with the hash as, say, their memory location?

Looking up different lists with the same contents would produce different results, even though comparing lists with the same contents would indicate them as equivalent.

What about Using a list literal in a dictionary lookup?

Answer (score 7):

Because lists are mutable, `dict` keys (and `set` members) need to be hashable, and hashing mutable objects is a bad idea because hash values *should* be computed on the basis of instance attributes.

In this answer, I will give some concrete examples, hopefully adding value on top of the existing answers. Every insight applies to the elements of the `set` datastructure as well.

**Example 1**: hashing a mutable object where the hash value is based on a mutable characteristic of the object.

```
>>> class stupidlist(list):
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return len(self)
... 
>>> stupid = stupidlist([1, 2, 3])
>>> d = {stupid: 0}
>>> stupid.append(4)
>>> stupid
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> d
{[1, 2, 3, 4]: 0}
>>> stupid in d
False
>>> stupid in d.keys()
False
>>> stupid in list(d.keys())
True
```

After mutating `stupid`, it cannot be found in the dict any longer because the hash changed. Only a linear scan over the list of the dict's keys finds `stupid`.

**Example 2**: ... but why not just a constant hash value?

```
>>> class stupidlist2(list):
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return id(self)
... 
>>> stupidA = stupidlist2([1, 2, 3])
>>> stupidB = stupidlist2([1, 2, 3])
>>> 
>>> stupidA == stupidB
True
>>> stupidA in {stupidB: 0}
False
```

That's not a good idea as well because equal objects should hash identically such that you can find them in a `dict` or `set`.

**Example 3**: ... ok, what about constant hashes across all instances?!

```
>>> class stupidlist3(list):
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return 1
... 
>>> stupidC = stupidlist3([1, 2, 3])
>>> stupidD = stupidlist3([1, 2, 3])
>>> stupidE = stupidlist3([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> 
>>> stupidC in {stupidD: 0}
True
>>> stupidC in {stupidE: 0}
False
>>> d = {stupidC: 0}
>>> stupidC.append(5)
>>> stupidC in d
True
```

Things seem to work as expected, but think about what's happening: when all instances of your class produce the same hash value, you will have a hash collision whenever there are more than two instances as keys in a `dict` or present in a `set`.

Finding the right instance with `my_dict[key]` or `key in my_dict` (or `item in my_set`) needs to perform as many equality checks as there are instances of `stupidlist3` in the dict's keys (in the worst case). At this point, the purpose of the dictionary - O(1) lookup - is completely defeated. This is demonstrated in the following timings (done with IPython).

**Some Timings for Example 3**

```
>>> lists_list = [[i]  for i in range(1000)]
>>> stupidlists_set = {stupidlist3([i]) for i in range(1000)}
>>> tuples_set = {(i,) for i in range(1000)}
>>> l = [999]
>>> s = stupidlist3([999])
>>> t = (999,)
>>> 
>>> %timeit l in lists_list
25.5 µs ± 442 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit s in stupidlists_set
38.5 µs ± 61.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
>>> %timeit t in tuples_set
77.6 ns ± 1.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

As you can see, the membership test in our `stupidlists_set` is even slower than a linear scan over the whole `lists_list`, while you have the expected super fast lookup time (factor 500) in a set without loads of hash collisions.

---

TL; DR: you can use `tuple(yourlist)` as `dict` keys, because tuples are immutable and hashable.

Comment: >>> x=(1,2,3321321321321,)
>>> id(x)
139936535758888
>>> z=(1,2,3321321321321,)
>>> id(z)
139936535760544
>>> id((1,2,3321321321321,))
139936535810768


These 3 have same tuple values but different id. So a dictionary with key x won't have any value for key z?

Comment: @Ashwani did you try it out?

Comment: Yes, It is working as expected, My doubt is all tuples with the same values have different ids. So on what basis this hash is calculated?

Comment: @Ashwani The hash of `x` and `z` is the same. If something about that is unclear, please open a new question.

Comment: How did you calculate the hash of x and z?

Comment: @Ashwani `hash(x)` and `hash(z)`.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer to your question is that the class list does not implement the method **hash** which is required for any object which wishes to be used as a key in a dictionary. However the reason why **hash** is not implemented the same way it is in say the tuple class (based on the content of the container) is because a list is mutable so editing the list would require the hash to be recalculated which may mean the list in now located in the wrong bucket within the underling hash table. Note that since you cannot modify a tuple (immutable) it doesn't run into this problem.

As a side note, the actual implementation of the dictobjects lookup is based on Algorithm D from Knuth Vol. 3, Sec. 6.4. If you have that book available to you it might be a worthwhile read, in addition if you're really, really interested you may like to take a peek at the developer comments on the actual [implementation of dictobject here.](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c?view=markup) It goes into great detail as to exactly how it works. There is also a [python lecture](http://vodpod.com/watch/4072099-pycon-2010the-mighty-dictionary-55) on the implementation of dictionaries which you may be interested in. They go through the definition of a key and what a hash is in the first few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Your awnser can be found here:

> Why Lists Can't Be Dictionary Keys
>
> Newcomers to Python often wonder why, while the language includes both
>   a tuple and a list type, tuples are usable as a dictionary keys, while
>   lists are not. This was a deliberate design decision, and can best be
>   explained by first understanding how Python dictionaries work.

Source & more info: http://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys

Answer (score -2):

According to the Python 2.7.2 documentation:

> An object is hashable if it has a hash value which never changes
> during its lifetime (it needs a `__hash__()` method), and can be
> compared to other objects (it needs an `__eq__()` or `__cmp__()` method).
> Hashable objects which compare equal must have the same hash value.
>
> Hashability makes an object usable as a dictionary key and a set
> member, because these data structures use the hash value internally.
>
> All of Python’s immutable built-in objects are hashable, while no
> mutable containers (such as lists or dictionaries) are. Objects which
> are instances of user-defined classes are hashable by default; they
> all compare unequal, and their hash value is their `id()`.

A tuple is immutable in the sense that you cannot add, remove or replace its elements, but the elements themselves may be mutable. List's hash value depends on the hash values of its elements, and so it changes when you change the elements.

Using id's for list hashes would imply that all lists compare differently, which would be surprising and inconvenient.

Answer (score -2):

> A Dictionary is a HashMap it stores map of your keys, value converted
>   to a hashed new key and value mapping.

something like (psuedo code):

```
{key : val}  
hash(key) = val
```

If you are wondering which are available options that can be used as key for your dictionary. Then

> anything which is **hashable(can be converted to hash, and hold static value i.e immutable so as to make a
>   hashed key as stated above)** is eligible but **as list or set objects can be vary on the go so hash(key) should also needs to vary just to be in sync with your list or set.**

You can try :

```
hash(<your key here>)
```

If it works fine it can be used as key for your dictionary or else convert it to something hashable.

---

**Inshort :**

1. Convert that list to `tuple(<your list>)`.
2. Convert that list to `str(<your list>)`.

Answer (score -2):

Simply we can keep in mind that the `dict` keys need to be **immutable** (to be exact, *hashable*). Lists are mutable (to be exact, lists do not provide a valid `__hash__` method).

Here an immutable object (unchangeable object) is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created. This is in contrast to a mutable object (changeable object), which can be modified after it is created.