# How to convert a list of tuples containing two lists into dictionary of key value pairs?

Tags: python

I have a list like this-

```
send_recv_pairs = [(['produce_send'], ['consume_recv']), (['Send'], ['Recv']), (['sender2'], ['receiver2'])]
```

I want something like

```
[ {['produce_send']:['consume_recv']},{['Send']:['Recv']},{['sender2']:['receiver2']}
```

How to do this?

Comment: A `list` cannot be a `key` in dictionary

Comment: You can use the contents of the lists as the keys, but not the lists themselves. But I think that's what you're supposed to do since the lists contain only one value

Answer (score 4):

You can not use `list` as the key of `dictionary`.
This Article explain the concept,

https://wiki.python.org/moin/DictionaryKeys

To be used as a dictionary key, an object must support the hash function (e.g. through **hash**), equality comparison (e.g. through **eq** or **cmp**), and must satisfy the correctness condition above.

And

lists do not provide a valid **hash** method.

```
>>> d = {['a']: 1}

    TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

If you want to specifically differentiate the key values you can use `tuple` as they `hash able`

```
{ (i[0][0], ): (i[1][0], )  for i in send_recv_pairs}

{('Send',): ('Recv',),
 ('produce_send',): ('consume_recv',),
 ('sender2',): ('receiver2',)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have lists as keys, only hashable types - strings, numbers, None and such.
If you still want to use a dictionary knowing that, then:

```
d={}
for tup in send_recv_pairs:
    d[tup[0][0]]=tup[1]
```

If you want the value to be string as well, use `tup[1][0]` instead of `tup[1]`

As a one liner:

```
d={tup[0][0]]:tup[1] for tup in list}  #tup[1][0] if you want values as strings
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check it over here, in the second way of creating distionary. 
https://developmentality.wordpress.com/2012/03/30/three-ways-of-creating-dictionaries-in-python/

A Simple way of doing it,

First of all, your tuple is tuple of lists, so better change it to tuple of strings (It makes more sense I guess)
Anyway simple way of working with your current tuple list can be like :

```
mydict = {}
for i in send_recv_pairs:
    print i
    mydict[i[0][0]]= i[1][0]
```

As others pointed out, you cannot use list as key to dictionary. So the term `i[0][0]` first takes the first element from the tuple - which is a list- and then the first element of list, which is the only element anyway for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
send_recv_pairs = [(['produce_send'], ['consume_recv']),
                   (['Send'], ['Recv']),
                   (['sender2'], ['receiver2'])]

send_recv_dict = {e[0][0]: e[1][0] for e in send_recv_pairs}
```

Resulting in...

```
>>> {'produce_send': 'consume_recv', 'Send': 'Recv', 'sender2': 'receiver2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers, you cannot use a list as a dictionary key as it is not hashable (see links in other answers).

You can therefore just use the values in your lists (assuming they stay as simple as in your example) to create the following two possibilities:

```
send_recv_pairs = [(['produce_send'], ['consume_recv']), (['Send'], ['Recv']), (['sender2'], ['receiver2'])]


result1 = {}

for t in send_recv_pairs:

    result1[t[0][0]] = t[1]

# without any lists

result2 = {}
for t in send_recv_pairs:

    result2[t[0][0]] = t[1][0]
```

Which respectively gives:

```
>>> result1
{'produce_send': ['consume_recv'], 'Send': ['Recv'], 'sender2': ['receiver2']}
>>> result2
{'produce_send': 'consume_recv', 'Send': 'Recv', 'sender2': 'receiver2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
res = { x[0]: x[1] for x in pairs } # or x[0][0]: x[1][0] if you wanna store inner values without list-wrapper
```

It's for Python 3 and when keys are unique. If you need collect list of values per key, instead of single value, than you may use something like `itertools.groupby` or map+reduce. Wrote about this in comments and I'll provide example.

And yes, list cannot store key-values, only dict's, but maybe it's just typo in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `list` as the dictionary key, but instead you may type-cast it as `tuple` to create the `dict` object.

Below is the sample example using a *dictionary comprehension*:

```
>>> send_recv_pairs = [(['produce_send'], ['consume_recv']), (['Send'], ['Recv']), (['sender2'], ['receiver2'])]

>>> {tuple(k): v for k, v in send_recv_pairs}
{('sender2',): ['receiver2'], ('produce_send',): ['consume_recv'], ('Send',): ['Recv']}
```

For details, take a look at: [*Why can't I use a list as a dict key in python?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257588/why-cant-i-use-a-list-as-a-dict-key-in-python)

---

However if your nested tuple pairs were not list, but any other *hashable* object pairs, you may have type-casted it to `dict` for getting the desired result. For example:

```
>>> my_list = [('key1', 'value1'), ('key2', 'value2')]

>>> dict(my_list)
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```