# Adding bracket in python list

Tags: python, dictionary

I got a list problem:

```
 position = self.request.POST.getlist('position')
 status = self.request.POST.getlist('tooth')

 a = dict((i, j) for i, j in zip(position, status) if j != '')

 print(a)
 {'14': 'status1', '15': 'status2', '13': 'status3'}
```

Is it possible to achieve format result like:

```
  {'14': [status1], [15]: [status2], [13]: [status3]}
```

Please.

Comment: status1, status2, status3 are variables?

Comment: python dictionaries cannot have lists as keys like in your desired output. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257588/why-cant-i-use-a-list-as-a-dict-key-in-python).

Comment: if you want the values to be lists, you could do something like: 
a = dict((i, [j]) for i, j in zip(position, status) if j != '')

Comment: You can certainly _print_ the data like that, by using the appropriate formatting commands, but are you sure you really want that exact format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
{k:[v] for k, v in a.items()}
```

This results in:

```
{'13': ['status3'], '15': ['status2'], '14': ['status1']}
```

Note that the keys are unchanged.  Your example shows some of them being converted to integers and embedded in lists, but lists cannot be dictionary keys.