# What is the relationship between immutable and hashable?

Tags: python

I found the immutable object has a **hash** property but mutable hasn't,so is that mean mutable≈hashable?
I also want to ask why and how.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the immutable object" or for that matter "the mutable object". Generators are mutable yet have a hash.

Comment: I illustrated the relationship [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52998879/3620003).