# What is the Python Equivalent function of Javascript Map()?

Tags: python

I am searching for a python equivalent code/function for the below javascript code.

```
let nameSetFlagMap = new Map();
```

Comment: `nameSetFlagMap = {}` perhaps? Might depend on how you use that value. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:node.js] (nor, really, [tag:javascript]). Please don't tag-spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ordered dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

nameSetFlagMap = OrderedDict()
nameSetFlagMap["a"] = "a"
nameSetFlagMap["b"] = "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for would be Dictionary.

```
nameSetFlagMap={}
#or
nameSetFlagMap=dict()
```

you can learn more about them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Both answers above are wrong because they do not have the same behavior as Map() from js

---

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
asd = OrderedDict()

asd2 = []

asd[asd2] = 123

asd2.append(444)

print(asd)

print(asd[asd2])
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nikel/asd.py", line 10, in <module>
    asd[asd2] = 123
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

---

```py
from collections import OrderedDict
asd = OrderedDict()

asd2 = {}

asd[asd2] = 123

asd2.append(444)

print(asd)

print(asd[asd2])
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nikel/asd.py", line 10, in <module>
    asd[asd2] = 123
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

---

```js
test_map = new Map()

test_map[555] = 666

list1 = []
list2 = [123]
list3 = []

test_map.set(list1, 'list1')
test_map.set(list2, 'list2')
test_map.set(list3, 'list3')

list2.push(4442)

console.log(test_map)

console.log(test_map.get(list1))
console.log(test_map.get(list2))
console.log(test_map.get(list3))
```

output:

```
Map(3) {
  [] => 'list1',
  [ 123, 4442 ] => 'list2',
  [] => 'list3',
  '555': 666
}
list1
list2
list3
```

I'm currently searching for analog too, so will update after I will find it.

But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7257711/12634253) looks like it is impossible.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with node.js, but that loooks to me like a trick as the `[]` is transformed into `''` as a Map key. You can use an empty string as a key in python, but not list or dict as they are mutable and unhashable.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I have used the Map not as it intended to be used. Updated answer.