# how to create dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
d={['R', 'P']:2,['R', 'S']:1,['P','S']:2}
```

trying to create this list to make the game rock paper scissors but i get an error,
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
looks like the list in the dict makes the error, any solve?

Comment: You can't, exactly due to the reason explained in the error. You can however use tuples.

Comment: see this why you cannot
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257588/why-cant-i-use-a-list-as-a-dict-key-in-python Replacing with tuples will do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use lists as keys in dictionary (or any non-hashable/mutable type). You can use tuples instead

```
d={('R', 'P'):2,('R', 'S'):1,('P','S'):2}
```