# set of sets and "in" operator

Tags: python, set

I was doing some coding exercises and I ended up using a `set` of `frozenset`s.
Here is the code:

```py
cities = 4
roads = [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0]]
roads = set([frozenset(road) for road in roads])
    
output = []
    
for i in range(cities-1):
    for j in range(i+1, cities):
        if set([i,j]) not in roads:
            output.append([i,j])
```

As you can see, the `if` in the nested `for` tests for the presence of the set in the set of sets.
However, it was my understanding that in this case, hashables need to be used with the `in` operator.

If I replace `set([i,j])` with `[i,j]`, I do get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

So, here is my question: why does it work with the set, which is not (as far as I know) hashable and not with the list?
Should it not also throw an error, what am I missing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/7257588

Comment: @Hcaertnit: That's not it. this is "a bit" more subtle.

Comment: `frozenset`s *are* hashable because they are immutable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my reading of the CPython source it appears that the test for `contains` checks if the key is found in the set; if not, and if the key is a `set` object, an attempt is made to convert the key to a `frozenset`, and then that key is tested. The same behavior exists for operations like `remove`, as seen here:

```
>>> s = set([frozenset([1,2])])
>>> s
{frozenset({1, 2})}
>>> s.remove(set([1,2]))
>>> s
set()
```

The code in question in the interpreter is the `set_contains()` function in `Objects/setobject.c`.

Comment: `[0,1]` _can_ be converted to a frozenset, yet it still causes an error.

Comment: You didn't mention that detail in your answer.

Comment: *setobject.c* (*set\_contains*).

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, found the answer in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), for anyone wondering:

*Note, the elem argument to the `__contains__()`, `remove()`, and `discard()` methods may be a set. To support searching for an equivalent frozenset, a temporary one is created from elem.*

Comment: I do not think this answers your question. You essentially wonder why `set().__contains__()` accepts an unhashable `{0,1}` but does not accept another unhashable `[0,1]`. It is not about comparison.

Comment: Could you provide the *URL*?

Comment: The actual answer is just a little further down the page: "Note, the _elem_ argument to the `__contains__()`, `remove()`, and `discard()` methods may be a set. To support searching for an equivalent frozenset, a temporary one is created from _elem_.".

Comment: @DYZ My bad, you are right, updated with the correct answer from DavisHerring