# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, dictionary, typeerror

This piece of code is giving me an error

```
TypeError: unhashable type: dict
```

Can anyone explain to me what the solution is?

```
negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))

def stopword_filtered_word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words if word not in stopset])

result=stopword_filtered_word_feats(negfeats)
```

Comment: RTD http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: It'd be useful to show the error report so we can see which line has the problem...

Comment: Also relevant: [Python hashable dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151658); [Check for mutability in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374006/). It would probably be better to write a new canonical from scratch to cover the general isue of "what can be used as a dictionary key? How can I work around the limitations?"

Comment: This issue might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986194/how-to-pass-dictionary-items-as-function-arguments-in-python

Answer (score 467):

You're trying to use a `dict` as a key to another `dict` or in a `set`. That does not work because the keys have to be hashable. As a general rule, only immutable objects (strings, integers, floats, frozensets, tuples of immutables) are hashable (though exceptions are possible). So this does not work:

```
>>> dict_key = {"a": "b"}
>>> some_dict[dict_key] = True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

To use a dict as a key you need to turn it into something that may be hashed first. If the dict you wish to use as key consists of only immutable values, you can create a hashable representation of it like this:

```
>>> key = frozenset(dict_key.items())
```

Now you may use `key` as a key in a `dict` or `set`:

```
>>> some_dict[key] = True
>>> some_dict
{frozenset([('a', 'b')]): True}
```

Of course you need to repeat the exercise whenever you want to look up something using a dict:

```
>>> some_dict[dict_key]                     # Doesn't work
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
>>> some_dict[frozenset(dict_key.items())]  # Works
True
```

If the `dict` you wish to use as key has values that are themselves dicts and/or lists, you need to recursively "freeze" the prospective key. Here's a starting point:

```
def freeze(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return frozenset((key, freeze(value)) for key, value in d.items())
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        return tuple(freeze(value) for value in d)
    return d
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, however still get error if the value is a dict or list (unhashable) , now I am using  hash(str(my_dict)), works fine for me.

Comment: just a note @StevenDu dictionaries do not guarantee order, so `str(my_dict)` could return two different strings for the same (or different, but equivalent) dicts

Comment: To convert the resulting frozenset back to dict, just call `dict(the_frozenset)`.

Comment: It seems to me that `frozenset(dict_key.items())` is potentially problematic in that two dicts with the same contents but different insertion order may not result in the same key. Adding a call to sorted() seems in order. E.g. `frozenset(sorted(dict_key.items()))` Additionally, frozenset seems like an odd choice given that sets are explicitly unordered. It probably works fine in practice, but tuple seems like a more logical choice to me. I went with `tuple(sorted(dict_key.items()))`

Comment: Although the answer mentions adding dicts to sets that case is not handled. Any takers?

Comment: @JasonHeiss In fact two `dict`s with different ordering of keys (but otherwise identical) come out as equal in Python (maybe not in other languages). Similarly `frozenset`s from two `dict`s with different ordering of keys. A simple test suffices to prove this.  So it seems that `sorted` would be redundant. Plus, if for whatever reason you did want to deal with sorted `dict`s, in most use cases I'm pretty sure it would make sense to sort when adding new items (equality functions would always require making new `frozenset`s, already expensive enough).

Comment: @JasonHeiss Plus (if I may), there is nothing "odd" about choosing to convert to a set: by definition you cannot have two identical keys in a `dict`.  `type(mydict.keys())` is actually `dict_keys`, but this is necessarily suitable for conversion into a `set` rather than a `tuple` (or `list`) (where you *can* have repeating elements).

Comment: @mikerodent You're absolutely right that dicts and sets are unordered. Not sure what I was thinking.

Comment: @JasonHeiss Not quite! Sorry: I feel a bit like a sort of hard taskmaster now. From Python (CPython) 3.7 `dict`s have also been ordered, by diktat of the BDFL: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html. But, as I say, a simple test shows that comparison still doesn't take account of order.

Comment: @mikerodent Yes indeed. I should just point to the docs that say this better than I'm managing to do. :) https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 42):

A possible solution might be to use the JSON dumps() method, so you can convert the dictionary to a string ---

```
import json

a={"a":10, "b":20}
b={"b":20, "a":10}
c = [json.dumps(a), json.dumps(b)]


set(c)
json.dumps(a) in c
```

Output -

```
set(['{"a": 10, "b": 20}'])
True
```

Comment: JSON is made up of ["an unordered set of name/value pairs"](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). So, changing the order of the name/value pairs will result in a "different" JSON string which will be registered as a new member of the set. In practice, this might not be a big deal since `json.dumps()` is likely predictable, but this is something to watch out for.

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me because I was thinking in Typescript, and tried to set a python dictionary up like this:

```
thing = { 'key': 'value' }
other_thing = {'other_key': 'other_value'}
my_dictionary = { thing, other_thing }
```

Then I tried:

```
my_dictionary = { thing: thing, other_thing: other_thing }
```

...which still did not work

What ended up working was...

```
my_dictionary = { 'thing': thing, 'other_thing': other_thing }
```

Funny how used we get to the little syntax tricks from different languages...

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if you try to use a dictionary as a key for another dictionary (e.g. `{{}: 1}`) or add a dictionary to a set (e.g. `{{}}`) or check if a dict exists in set/dict_keys (e.g. `{} in set()`) or use a column of dicts as a grouper in pandas groupby.

Possible solutions:

##### 1. `dict.items()` -> `tuple`

If insertion order of the dicts is important (which is lost if converted to frozensets), then refactor your code to convert the dict(s) to be used as dict key/added into a set into a tuple. For the example, the problem in the OP was that there was an attempt to use a dictionary (returned from `word_feats` function) as a key for another dictionary. For example,

```py
# dict as key of another dict
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
d2 = {d1: 3}                                # <--- TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
d2 = {tuple(d1.items()): 3}                 # <--- OK

# dicts in a set
st = {d1, d2}                               # <--- TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
st = {tuple(x.items()) for x in (d1, d2)}   # <--- OK

# membership tests
d1 in d2                                    # <--- TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
tuple(d1.items()) in d2                     # True
```

So for the example in the OP, instead of returning a `dict`, returning a `tuple` solves the problem.

```py
def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])     # <--- TypeError

def word_feats(words):
    return tuple((word, True) for word in words)      # <--- OK
```

This solution is useful if you were trying to cache a dictionary returned from function using the `@functools.lru_cache()` decorator and got this error. Refactoring the function to return a tuple instead solves the error.

##### 2. `dict` -> `str`

Another way is to simply convert the dictionary into a string. Similar to `tuple()`, it preserves insertion order. Then if the stringified key needs to be converted back into a dict, `ast.literal_eval()` from the standard library can be used to recover it.

```py
import ast

d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
d2 = {str(d1): 3}                               # {"{'a': 1, 'b': 2}": 3}

str(d1) in d2                                   # True

[ast.literal_eval(key) for key in d2.keys()]    # [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

##### 3. `dict.items()` -> `frozenset`

Because frozensets don't preserve order, it's ideal if you wanted to add dicts into a set, perhaps to find unique dicts in a list. Then to recover the original dictionary from the frozensets, call `dict()` on each frozenset. For example,

```py
lst = [{1:3, 2:0}, {2:0, 1:3}, {2:3}]      # list of dicts
set(lst)                                   # <--- TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

st = {frozenset(d.items()) for d in lst}   # convert each dict into a frozenset
# convert back into a list of unique dicts
[dict(d) for d in st]                      # [{2: 3}, {2: 0, 1: 3}]
```

As the output of the last line of code above shows, only one of `lst[0]` and `lst[1]` was correctly kept, since `lst[0]==lst[1]` is True.

##### 4. `dict` -> `json.dumps()`

If the dicts are json serializable, then converting to json objects can be used to find unique dicts in a list too. If you want to make sure that the order of keys don't matter, use the `sort_keys=` parameter of `json.dumps()`. However, one important thing to note is that json requires the keys to be strings, so if the keys are numeric (as below), then converting to json and back into a dict may not recover the original dict if there are non-string keys.

```py
import json
lst1 = [{1:3, 2:0}, {2:0, 1:3}]
[json.loads(j) for j in {json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True) for d in lst1}] 
# [{'1': 3, '2': 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a set of dicts (which you can't create since dict are mutable) I recommend you use instead a dict of dict. You can then combine that with @StevenDu's suggestion

```
mydict: Dict[int, dict] = {}
d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
mydict[hash(str(d1))] = d1
```

Please note that instead of 'hash(str(d1))' you could use any custom way to get a unique key for your dict.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def frozendict(d: dict):
    keys = sorted(d.keys())
    return tuple((k, d[k]) for k in keys)
```

Implementing the function above returns an immutable structure, and we prefer sorting the key to prevent out-of-order iterations.

Comment: It would be better if you explain why this is a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer has a great guide on what to do when answering a question.

Answer (score -1):

There is a good package called [frozendict](https://github.com/Marco-Sulla/python-frozendict)

```
pip3 install frozendict
```

```
from frozendict import frozendict
```

And then either

```
d = frozendict(role="user", content=prompt)
```

or

```
d = frozendict(my_dict)
```