# How to pass dictionary items as function arguments in python?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, dictionary

My code

1st file:

```
data = {'school':'DAV', 'standard': '7', 'name': 'abc', 'city': 'delhi'}
my_function(*data)
```

2nd file:

```
my_function(*data):
    schoolname  = school
    cityname = city
    standard = standard
    studentname = name
```

in the above code, only keys of "data" dictionary were get passed to `my_function()`, but i want key-value pairs to pass. How to correct this ?

I want the `my_function()` to get modified like this

```
my_function(school='DAV', standard='7', name='abc', city='delhi')
```

and this is my requirement, give answers according to this

*EDIT:* dictionary key *class* is changed to *standard*

Comment: Don't use variable names that are default objects in Python, such as the word `class`.

Comment: _...and this is my requirement, give answers according to this_ -- Ugh, a bit harsh. But a good question, nonetheless.

Comment: @pfabri, it's quite clear from reading the question that English is not user's native language, so it's very possible that the harshness was unintended and that's just how they translated it to English.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

If you want to use them like that, define the function with the variable names as normal:

```py
def my_function(school, standard, city, name):
    schoolName  = school
    cityName = city
    standardName = standard
    studentName = name
```

Now you can use `**` when you *call* the function:

```py
data = {'school':'DAV', 'standard': '7', 'name': 'abc', 'city': 'delhi'}

my_function(**data)
```

and it will work as you want.

**P.S.** Don't use reserved words such as `class`.(e.g., use `klass` instead)

Comment: i have this line def my_function(*data), modify your code according to this line

Comment: you mean to recompile whole python interpreter to work like you want it to work?

Comment: @markcial is there any way to implement in code as i like ?

Comment: @Patrick Not a chance, the only way is the one that RemcoGerlih proposed. He has a working sample of code, yours has failed, then is logical to follow their guidelines

Comment: @RemcoGerlich its giving me error in def my_function(..) line for TypeError: my_function() got an unexpected keyword argument 'school'

Comment: Then you didn't put 'school' in the arguments of the function.

Comment: Hello @RemcoGerlich and the rest, is there a way to pass values of only selected keys in a dictionary as parameters to a function?

Comment: @MayankChoudhary: either first construct a new dictionary with only the selected keys and pass it with `**`, or just do `my_function(mykey1=mydict["mykey1"], ...)`. There is no automatic way to call a function like that.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich : Thought so. Was wondering if you had something up your sleeve. :-)
Thank you for your reply. I went about creating a new dictionaries.

Comment: Can we dynamically filter using the length of keys in such dictionaries

Answer (score 67):

*data interprets arguments as tuples, instead you have to pass **data which interprets the arguments as dictionary.

```
data = {'school':'DAV', 'class': '7', 'name': 'abc', 'city': 'pune'}


def my_function(**data):
    schoolname  = data['school']
    cityname = data['city']
    standard = data['class']
    studentname = data['name']
```

You can call the function like this:

```
my_function(**data)
```

Answer (score 18):

You can just pass it

```
def my_function(my_data):
    my_data["schoolname"] = "something"
    print my_data
```

or if you really want to

```
def my_function(**kwargs):
    kwargs["schoolname"] = "something"
    print kwargs
```

Comment: made my day :-)

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between the two. The first passes a reference the second copies the data. If you pass a reference and the dictionary gets changed inside the function it will be changed outside the function as well which can cause very bad side effects.