# How to pass dictionary as an argument of function and how to access them in the function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried doing this:

```
def func(dict):
    if dict[a] == dict[b]:
        dict[c] = dict[a]
    return dict

num =  { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2}
print(func(**num))
```

But it gives in TypeError.
Func got an unexpected argument a

Comment: First change `If` to `if`. Second, do not use `dict` as a parameter or variable name, it is a builtin. Third, why are you saying `func(**num)` instead of `func(num)`?

Comment: If was a typing error while asking the question. Being a newbie I didn't know dict is reserved key. About using **num, I was trying to follow one of the earlier stack overflow answers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21986301

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters

Answer (score 8):

Using ** will unpack the dictionary, in your case you should just pass a reference to `num` to func, i.e.

`print(func(num))`

(Unpacking `**` is the equivalent of `func(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)`), e.g.

```
def func(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2

args = {"arg1": 3,"arg2": 4}
print(func(**args))
```

Comment: The first one should be `print(func(num))`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

Two main problems:

- passing the ** argument is incorrect.  Just pass the dictionary; Python will handle the referencing.
- you tried to reference locations with uninitialized variable names.  Letters a/b/c are literal strings in your dictionary.

Code:

```
def func(table):
    if table['a'] == table['b']:
        table['c'] = table['a']
    return table

num =  { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2}
print(func(num))
```

---

Now, let's try a couple of test cases: one with a & b different, one matching:

```
>>> letter_count =  { "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 2}
>>> print(func(letter_count))
{'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'a': 1}

>>> letter_count =  { "a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 2}
>>> print(func(letter_count))
{'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'a': 1}
```

Comment: Also, it would be good to point out that using `dict` for a name is usually a very silly decision.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this i don't know why it works but it just work

```
gender_ = {'Male': 0, 'Female': 1}

def number_wordy(row, **dic):
   for key, value in dic.items() :
       if row == str(key) :
            return value
print(number_wordy('Female', **gender_ ))
```

Comment: hi, eman please add space/tab in python program, as space/tab syntax is important in python.