# passing dynamically all dictionary <key, value> as function arguments

Tags: python, function, dictionary, dynamic, arguments

i got a given dictionary - for instance:
x = {'a': 1,'b': 2, 'c': 3}
what i would like to do is sending all keys and values to some function.
for instance:
func1(a=1,b=2,c=3)

(for other dictionary y = {'z': 8,'x': 9, 'w': 11,'p': 88}
the function call will be:
func1(z=8,x=9,w=11,p=88))

is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: use `**` like so: `func1(**my_dict)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a built in feature of python, consider the following:

```
x = {'a': 1,'b': 2, 'c': 3}
func1(**x)
```

is the same as:

```
func1(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

I recommend you read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) on defining fuctions

Answer (score 0):

These exemples might be useful. However it really depends on what's the final function

[How to pass dictionary items as function arguments in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986194/how-to-pass-dictionary-items-as-function-arguments-in-python)

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-passing-dictionary-as-arguments-to-function/

[How to pass dictionary as an argument of function and how to access them in the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907174/how-to-pass-dictionary-as-an-argument-of-function-and-how-to-access-them-in-the)