# How can I evaluate all the combinations obtained by GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

By using GridSearchCV I can obtain clf.cv_results_['params'] and I would like to run over all the possible combinations and printing some probabilities:

```
for params in zip(clf.cv_results_['params']):
        print(params)
        clf= SVC(params)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        z_test=clf.predict(X_test)
        print("Probability 1:", prob_error(y_test,z_test))
        print("Probability 2:", average_error(y_test,z_test))
```

However, in params I obtain this:

```
({'C': 1000, 'gamma': 1000, 'tol': 2},)
```

How can I transform this in order to do the fit of the algorithm? Because this code has an error in "clf.fit(X_train, y_train)":

```
TypeError: must be real number, not tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using zip on the `clf.cv_results_['params']`. Remove that and do it like below:

```
for params in clf.cv_results_['params']:
        print(params)
        clf= SVC(**params)
        clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
        z_test=clf.predict(X_test)
        print("Probability 1:", prob_error(y_test,z_test))
        print("Probability 2:", average_error(y_test,z_test))
```

See this for more details:

- [How to pass dictionary items as function arguments in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986194/how-to-pass-dictionary-items-as-function-arguments-in-python)