# Python: Forward a dictionary to another function

Tags: python, dictionary, forwarding

I need to forward a dictionary to another function (that I can't change). Both my function and the target function look like this:

```
def myFunc(arg, **args):
def targetFunc(arg, **args):
```

In my code, I used to call the target function directly:

```
a = targetFunc(123, aaa=4, bbb=5, ccc=6)
```

and I have to add another layer to process the extra arguments passed as a dictionary, before forwarding to the target function:

```
a = myFunc(123, aaa=4, bbb=5, ccc=6)
```

And now my function receives `123` as `arg`, and a dictionary:

```
{'bbb": 5, 'ccc': 6, 'aaa': 4}
```

as `args`. The problem is, I can't modify the target function in any way. It may be a function from a package like `subprocess.run`. I've tried supplying the dictionary directly but Python says

```
def myFunc(arg, **args):
    print(args)
    targetFunc(arg, args)

def targetFunc(arg, **args):
    print(args)
```

```
TypeError: targetFunc() takes 1 positional argument but 2 was given
```

I can write `myFunc` in any way. How can I forward this dictionary to the target function, so it receives the same dictionary as its `args`?

Note: It's possible to construct a string then `eval()` it, but I don't want to do it that way.

Comment: `a = targetFunc(123, **{'bbb': 5, 'ccc': 6, 'aaa': 4})`

Comment: @MartijnPieters How is this question unclear? I'm just new to Python

Comment: @Rawing That works. It looks like a valid answer, could you please post it?

Comment: No need for an answer, we have plenty of duplicates for this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334655/passing-a-dictionary-to-a-function-in-python-as-keyword-parameters) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986194/how-to-pass-dictionary-items-as-function-arguments-in-python) for example.

Comment: @iBug: I'll re-open and close as a duplicate, but next time include a proper MCVE. You could have mocked up `targetFunc()` and a minimal implementation for `myFunc()` that reproduces the behaviour.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think the description is enough... Why do you think it lacks a MCVE?

Comment: We're programmers - code is easier for us to understand than words ;)