# Using variable to pass options to Tkinter widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make GUI with Tkinter, but I have occured a problem. My GUI is going to have a lot of very similar buttons with a lot of options (font, width, height, command etc.) and I would rather like to write name of variable, which store repeating options than repeat all commands over and over again.

I don´t even know if this possible.
I tried save options as string in variable and then pass it into variable, but it raises: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'`

This is example of my buttons:

`Num3 = Tk.Button(main, text="3", width = 2, height = 2, font = "Arial 16", command=lambda: nex("3"))
 Num4 = Tk.Button(main, text="4", width = 2, height = 2, font = "Arial 16", command=lambda: nex("4"))`

And I would like that it look like this:

`Var = 'main, width = 2, height = 2, font = "Arial 16",'
Num3 = Tk.Button(Var, text="3",command=lambda: nex("3"))
Num4 = Tk.Button(Var, text="4",command=lambda: nex("4"))`

But it raises that `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'`

Thanks for answers, people.

Comment: Don't use variable names that start with with Capital letters. See [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save them inside a dictionary, like this

```py
import tkinter as tk

main = tk.Tk()

options = {"text": "Hello!", "font": "Arial 16", "width": 2, "height": 2}

Num4 = tk.Button(main, **options)
Num4.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

See this question [How to pass dictionary items as function arguments in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986194/how-to-pass-dictionary-items-as-function-arguments-in-python).