# Python: Get value from list of dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dicts like this:

```py
    [{'sftp_conn': 'conn_1', 'sftp_path': 'path_1'}, 
     {'sftp_conn': 'conn_2', 'sftp_path': 'path_2'}
    ]
```

I know how to fetch values from the list of values

I want to loop each in the list and assign values to the variables

```py
  id =1   sftp_conn = 'conn_1' , sftp_path = 'path_1'
```

then next

```py
  id=2  sftp_conn = 'conn_2' , sftp_path = 'path_2'
```

I have an Airflow code as below, so I want to iterate and pass the values to sftp_path and sftp_conn_id

```py
    for count, sftp in enumerate(sftp_list):
                s3_to_sftp = S3ToSftpOperator(
                    task_id=f's3_to_sftp_{count}',
                    sftp_path=  ,
                    sftp_conn_id= ,
                    s3_conn_id=S3_CONN_ID,
                )
```

Comment: Are id's available separately? Where do you get id's from?

Comment: Its not separate , but like we have enumerate in list which gets 0 , 1

Comment: Why did you not write the code that does the loop and assigns the values to variables?

Comment: I was able to do for a list of values, honestly, I am trying with list of dict values

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986194/how-to-pass-dictionary-items-as-function-arguments-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to enumerate over the list while passing `start=1` to start counting from 1 instead of 0. Please let me know if this is not what you meant.

```py
li = [{'sftp_conn': 'conn_1', 'sftp_path': 'path_1'},{'sftp_conn': 'conn_2', 'sftp_path': 'path_2'}]

for item in enumerate(li, start=1):
    taskID, sftp_conn, sftp_path = item[0], item[1]['sftp_conn'], item[1]['sftp_path']
    #print(taskID, sftp_conn, sftp_path)
```

When that print line is uncommented, this will be the output for above list:

```
1 conn_1 path_1
2 conn_2 path_2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily iterate over it and use values() dict method.

```py
d = [{'sftp_conn': 'conn_1', 'sftp_path': 'path_1'}, 
    {'sftp_conn': 'conn_2', 'sftp_path': 'path_2'}
    ]
    
x = [(' '.join(i.values())).split(' ') for i in d]
v1, v2, v3, v4 = x[0][0], x[0][1], x[1][0], x[1][1]
```

Comment: I want to pass the values to the variable example ` sftp_conn = conn_1 `and `sftp_path = path_1` for first list then iterate to second list

Comment: great, Also I need to enumerate values as we have in list enumerate which gives 0 ,1

Comment: @Kar I don't know If I'm understanding correctly, would you like to assign values to each dictionary? Or do you want to name each dictionary?

Comment: Updated the original question with detailed