# unhashable type 'dict' in celery

Tags: python, celery

I just wrote a simple celery code,that will just add two number and print it,using celery..using the following code:

```
from scheduling.celery import app

*@app.task
def add(x, y):
    print("sum is "+str(x+y))*
```

But the problem is when i call this function using :

```
*add.apply_async((3, 4))*
```

there's a raise exception error saying that

```
> Task
> celerytasktest.simplecelerytask.add[bafe33b6-3329-406a-b5c0-43eee9228273]
> raised unexpected: TypeError("unhashable type: 'dict'",)
```

I tried two days to find out the problem,but failed.

I am using the celery version 3.1.9

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are calling wrong your `add` function. Instead of `x, y`, you are adding `tuple`. Same problem describes [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict)

Answer (score 3):

You should call your function like this:

```
function.apply_async(
args = [param1, param2, ...],
kwargs = {k : v}, ...})
```

With your add functions, the statement will be:

```
add.apply_async(args = [3,4])
```

You can check the documentation http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error when running celery as a daemon with the celery multi start command. Oddly enough, changing the name of one of my queues from q3 to q4 seems to be what fixed it.