# How make unique a list of nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, unique, python-2.6

I've got the following list of nested dictionaries:

```
[{'permission': 'full',
  'permission_type': 'allow',
  'trustee': {'id': 'SID:S-1-5-32-545',
              'name': 'Users',
              'type': 'group'}},
 {'permission': 'full',
  'permission_type': 'allow',
  'trustee': {'id': 'SID:S-1-5-32-545',
              'name': 'Users',
              'type': 'group'}},
 {'permission': 'full',
  'permission_type': 'allow',
  'trustee': {'id': 'SID:S-1-5-32-544',
              'name': 'Administrators',
              'type': 'group'}}]
```

I want to make it unique and have tried different suggestions with no success.
Can someone help to make it unique in python 2.6? There is no key/unique field in the data above.
I expect the following result (one member of the list is removed as a full duplicate):

```
[{'permission': 'full',
  'permission_type': 'allow',
  'trustee': {'id': 'SID:S-1-5-32-545',
              'name': 'Users',
              'type': 'group'}},
 {'permission': 'full',
  'permission_type': 'allow',
  'trustee': {'id': 'SID:S-1-5-32-544',
              'name': 'Administrators',
              'type': 'group'}}]
```

Comment: can you define "uniqify" exactly?

Comment: Unique by what measure? That all values for given keys are the same? Or are is it fuzzier than that?

Comment: remove duplicate items where the dictionaries contain the same data

Comment: the top 2 list items are identical

Comment: @Intra which one should removed? remember list is an ordered sequence

Comment: I've edited the question, order of the list is not important

Comment: Please specify in your question unique by `id`'s `trustee` field.

Comment: If your dictionaries have the same keys in all instances, a simple way to do it would be to do: `list(set([str(c) for c in my_list]))`

Comment: @M.Klugerford: that depends on the insertion order of the keys being the same then; the way dictionaries list key-values can *differ* based on their insertion and deletion history. You'd have equal dictionaries, but *different string representations*. Besides, your method builds a set of unique strings, not actual dictionaries.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico: Presumably it also needs to be unique by the `permission` and `permission_type` fields. E.g. **all key-value combinations**.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That is true, however, doesn't recasting an existing dict into a new one essentially eliminate the difference in insertion / deletion order? In that case, will `str(dict(c))` instead of `dict(c)` be valid?

Oh and true, my method builds a set of strings.

Comment: @M.Klugerford: sure, but you still end up with duplicates then, as the strings are used to track unique dictionaries. Those strings will still differ.

Comment: Surely doable in O(N^2), but can it be done faster? I.e. hash a hairy POD structure canonically somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd need to track if you have seen a dictionary already. Unfortunately, dictionaries are not hashable, and do not track order, so you need to convert dictionaries to something that *is* hashable. A `frozenset()` of the key-value pairs (as tuples) would do, but then you need to flatten recursively:

```
def set_from_dict(d):
    return frozenset(
        (k, set_from_dict(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v)
        for k, v in d.iteritems())
```

These `frozenset()` objects represent the dictionary values enough to track unique items:

```
seen = set()
result = []
for d in inputlist:
    representation = set_from_dict(d)
    if representation in seen:
        continue
    result.append(d)
    seen.add(representation)
```

This preserves the original order of your input list, minus duplicates. If you are using Python 2.7 and up, an `OrderedDict` would have been helpful here, but you are using Python 2.6, so we need to do it slightly more verbosely.

The above approach takes O(N) time, one step per input dictionary, as testing against a set takes only O(1) constant time.

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = [{'permission': 'full',
...   'permission_type': 'allow',
...   'trustee': {'id': 'SID:S-1-5-32-545',
...               'name': 'Users',
...               'type': 'group'}},
...  {'permission': 'full',
...   'permission_type': 'allow',
...   'trustee': {'id': 'SID:S-1-5-32-545',
...               'name': 'Users',
...               'type': 'group'}},
...  {'permission': 'full',
...   'permission_type': 'allow',
...   'trustee': {'id': 'SID:S-1-5-32-544',
...               'name': 'Administrators',
...               'type': 'group'}}]
>>> def set_from_dict(d):
...     return frozenset(
...         (k, set_from_dict(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v)
...         for k, v in d.iteritems())
... 
>>> seen = set()
>>> result = []
>>> for d in inputlist:
...     representation = set_from_dict(d)
...     if representation in seen:
...         continue
...     result.append(d)
...     seen.add(representation)
... 
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(result)
[{'permission': 'full',
  'permission_type': 'allow',
  'trustee': {'id': 'SID:S-1-5-32-545', 'name': 'Users', 'type': 'group'}},
 {'permission': 'full',
  'permission_type': 'allow',
  'trustee': {'id': 'SID:S-1-5-32-544',
              'name': 'Administrators',
              'type': 'group'}}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot install anything on the system and limited to python 2.6 and don't have "collections", I've tried to run set_from_dict on my list and getting the following error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Comment: @Intra: already adjusted for. :-)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like the most efficient way of doing it!

Answer (score 1):

Your items are `dict` so you won't be able to use `set` directly (check frozenset or [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict)).
But you still can compare the items:

```
>>> l[0]==l[1]
True
>>> l[0]==l[2]
False
```

So simply add your elements to a new list if it's not already present:

```
>>> l2=[]
>>> for i in l:
...   if i not in l2:
...     l2.append(i)
...
>>> pprint(l2)
[{'permission': 'full',
  'permission_type': 'allow',
  'trustee': {'id': 'SID:S-1-5-32-545', 'name': 'Users', 'type': 'group'}},
 {'permission': 'full',
  'permission_type': 'allow',
  'trustee': {'id': 'SID:S-1-5-32-544',
              'name': 'Administrators',
              'type': 'group'}}]
```

Comment: This takes quadratic time as you now test *each new dictionary* against all dictionaries seen so far.

Comment: What Martijn said; it's ok for short lists, where it has less overhead than Martijn's method, although it will get bogged down for large lists. Perhaps we need a timeit showdown to see where the break-even point is...

Comment: @PM2Ring: the dictionary comparisons do the same work my conversion to sets does, when comparing values; the keys are the same here. The only difference is that the comparison is done in C. But this method does far more comparisons; that 'break-even' point will be lower than you think.