# Issues with the addition of duplicate items by django_rest_framework ListSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using a combination of a PhoneGap app and a Django-based backend to record location data points for a research project.

The PhoneGap app will bundle up multiple data points and pushes them to a django-rest-framework API endpoint, for example:

```
[{
    "speed": -1,
    "time": 1487292133229.221,
    "longitude": 172.123456,
    "bearing": -1,
    "location_type": "current",
    "latitude": -43.123456,
    "accuracy": 65,
    "heading": -1,
    "altitude": 3.585018873214722,
    "altitudeAccuracy": 10
}, ...
]
```

However because of how the PhoneGap app manages location, many of the points are duplicated in the JSON that is pushed.

In order to try and resolve this, I've overridden the ListSerializer to go through the incoming data and compare it to what's already in the database by computing an (unencrypted) unique hash based on timestamp and user id (who uploaded it), and then seeing if something with the same hash already exists. This approach was taken because the actual location data is encrypted before being added to the database.

```python
class DatumListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """ Only append objects if the count of existing objects is 0 (i.e. it is unique),
            and it does not appear elsewhere in the list to be committed. """
        objects = []

        for obj in validated_data:
            hashed_value = generate_hash(obj['timestamp'], obj['user'].id)

            if Datum.objects.filter(hash=hashed_value).count()==0:
                objects.append(Datum.objects.create(user=obj.pop('user').id, **obj))

        return objects
```

This approach manages to catch most of the duplicates, but not all of them. Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing non-duplicates to be added? Should I put a unique constraint on the 'hash' field of the Datum model and then silently ignore inserts that cause an IntegrityError?

Thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since your json itself is corrupted with duplicates. I'd recommend cleaning your json first thing after you receive it at the backend (django). You can try an approach given here  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33955470/4815238

Once the JSON is clean, then create your required objects. Hope this helps.