# Issues while inserting data in cloudant DB

Tags: python, python-2.7, cloudant, python-cloudant

I am working a project, where in I am suppose to get some user input through web application, and send that data to cloudant DB. I am using python for the use case. Below is the sample code:

```
import requests
import json


dict_key ={}
key = frozenset(dict_key.items())   
doc={
{
    "_ID":"1",
    "COORD1":"1,1",
    "COORD2":"1,2",
    "COORD3":"2,1",
    "COORD4":"2,2",
    "AREA":"1",
    "ONAME":"abc",
    "STYPE":"black",
    "CROPNAME":"paddy",
    "CROPPHASE":"initial",
    "CROPSTARTDATE":"01-01-2017",
    "CROPTYPE":"temp",
    "CROPTITLE":"rice",
    "HREADYDATE":"06-03-2017",
    "CROPPRICE":"1000",
    "WATERRQ":"1000",
    "WATERSRC":"borewell"

        }
}


auth = ('uid', 'pwd')
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

post_url = "server_IP".format(auth[0])

req = requests.put(post_url,  auth=auth,headers=headers,  data=json.dumps(doc))
#req =  requests.get(post_url, auth=auth)
print json.dumps(req.json(), indent=1)
```

When I am running the code, I am getting the below error:

```
     "WATERSRC":"borewell"
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I searched a bit, and found below stackflow link as a prospective resolution

[TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict)

It says that "To use a dict as a key you need to turn it into something that may be hashed first. If the dict you wish to use as key consists of only immutable values, you can create a hashable representation of it like this:

```
key = frozenset(dict_key.items())"
```

I have below queries:

1) I have tried using it in my code above,but I am not sure if I have used it correctly.

2) To put the data in the cloudant DB, I am using Python module "requests". In the code,  I am using the below line to put the data in the DB:

```
req = requests.put(post_url,  auth=auth,headers=headers,  data=json.dumps(doc))
```

But I am getting below error:

> "reason": "Only GET,HEAD,POST allowed"

I searched on that as well, and I found IBM BLuemix document about it as follows

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/Cloudant/basics/index.html#cloudant-basics

As I referred the document, I can say that I am using the right option. But may be I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding a document to the database and you know the the `_id`, then you need to do an HTTP POST. Here's some slightly modified code:

```
import requests
import json

doc={
    "_id":"2",
    "COORD1":"1,1",
    "COORD2":"1,2",
    "COORD3":"2,1",
    "COORD4":"2,2",
    "AREA":"1",
    "ONAME":"abc",
    "STYPE":"black",
    "CROPNAME":"paddy",
    "CROPPHASE":"initial",
    "CROPSTARTDATE":"01-01-2017",
    "CROPTYPE":"temp",
    "CROPTITLE":"rice",
    "HREADYDATE":"06-03-2017",
    "CROPPRICE":"1000",
    "WATERRQ":"1000",
    "WATERSRC":"borewell"
}

auth = ('admin', 'admin')
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
post_url = 'http://localhost:5984/mydb'
req = requests.post(post_url,  auth=auth,headers=headers,  data=json.dumps(doc))
print json.dumps(req.json(), indent=1)
```

Notice that

- the `_id` field is supplied in the doc and is lower case
- the request call is a POST not a PUT
- the `post_url` contains the name of the database being written to - in this case `mydb`

N.B in the above example I am writing to local CouchDB, but replacing the URL with your Cloudant URL and adding correct credentials should get this working for you.