# 'language_counter': Counter() TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python

I wrote this Python script

```
with open('survey_data/survey_results_public.csv', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    dev_type_info = {}

    for line in csv_reader:
        dev_types = line['DevType'].split(';')

        for dev_type in dev_types:
            dev_type_info.setdefault(dev_type_info, {
                'total': 0,
                'language_counter': Counter()
            })
```

but I get this error

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-34-0dd498f86be7> in <module>
>      14             dev_type_info.setdefault(dev_type_info, {
>      15                 'total': 0,
> ---> 16                 'language_counter': Counter()
>      17             })
> 
> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

can anyone shade light upon this error, what is it and how do I solve it? Thank you

Comment: `dict` can't be key. Why are you using a dictionary as a key in itself? even if you could it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Maybe it's a data type conversion problem. See this article: http://net-informations.com/python/iq/unhashable.htm.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict)

Comment: Why are you using `setdefault` over `defaultdict`?

Comment: i fixed that now it is working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error because You're trying to use a `dict` as a key to another `dict`. Correct the below line of code:

```py
dev_type_info.setdefault(dev_type_info, { ..
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you meant :

```py
for dev_type in dev_types:
  dev_type_info.setdefault(dev_type, {
    'total': 0,
    'language_counter': Counter()
   })
```

as the usage for dict.setdefault is a key as the first parameter, not the dict itself.

```
dict.setdefault(key, default=None)
```