# defining dictionary in python getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, dictionary

i am trying to create a dictionary like something below:

```
frnd_detail1 = {
    {'name':'AD', 'age': 30}, {'name':'AKB', 'age':90},  {'name':'SD', 'age':40}
}
```

but i am getting the below error message as:

```
File "<ipython-input-72-a0d88fef112d>", line 4, in <module>
    {'name':'SD', 'age':40}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

why it is so, please provide some details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) (by accident I guess) by surrounding your dictionaries with curly braces `{}`.

In Python you can create sets using `{}` like this:

```
>>> my_set = {1,2,3}
>>> print(type(my_set))
<type 'set'>
```

Sets can only have values that are hashable. A `dict` isn't hashable which is why you get the error. You might want to create a `list` instead by replacing your outer `{}` with `[]` like this:

```
frnd_detail1 = [{'name': 'AD', 'age': 30}, {'name': 'AKB', 'age': 90}, {'name': 'SD', 'age': 40}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to create a dictionary of dictionaries or list of dictionaries.

If its a dict of dicts, then you need to give a key for its value, and not just ut each dictionary independently.

If its a list of dicts, you can append each dict into a list.