# MongoDB bucket operation with unhashable type: 'dict' in mongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Here is some sample document(I only show used filed, there are other fields in document):

```
{"id":1111,"info":{"score":90,"class":"algorithm","room":101}}
{"id":1112,"info":{"score":60,"class":"java","room":401}}
{"id":1113,"info":{"score":100,"class":"python","room":301}}
```

What I want do is to compute the score distribution, I use the bucket operation, according to https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/index.html。

```
pipeline = {
        {"$match": {"_id": ObjectId(_id)}},
        {"$bucket": {
            "groupBy": "$info.score",
            "boundaries": [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100],
            "output": {
                "count": {"$sum": 1}
            }
        }}
    }
score_distribution = list(Students.objects.aggregate(*pipeline))
```

However, I met the error:

```
"count": {"$sum": 1}
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

I can't find the reason why there is type error, can anyone give some suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys, I made a super edit mistake.
The pipeline should be array not a dict.

```
pipeline = [
        {"$match": {"_id": ObjectId(_id)}},
        {"$bucket": {
            "groupBy": "$info.score",
            "boundaries": [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100],
            "output": {
                "count": {"$sum": 1}
            }
        }}
    ]
```