# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' while applying a decorator function

Tags: python-3.x, function, dictionary

I have the below code defining the `decorator` and the `decorated` functions. When I call the decorated function, I am getting a TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'. Where is the problem? Appreciate inputs. I am using `jupyter` notebook on my desktop.

```
def memorize(func):
    """ Store the results of a decorated function for last lookup"""
    #store results in a dictionary that maps arguments to results
    cache = {}
    # define the wrappaer function that the decorator returns
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        #if these arguments haven't been seen before
        if (args, kwargs) not in cache:
            cache[(args,kwargs)] = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return cache[(args, kwargs)]
    return wrapper

@memorize
def slow_function(a,b):
    print('Sleeping.....')
    time.sleep(5)
    return a+b

slow_function(3,7)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attempt to use `(args,kwargs)` as key (or part of the key) in `cache[(args,kwargs)]`, `kwargs` is of `dict` type. `dict` types are not able to be used as keys in dictionaries. In fact, no mutable data structures can be used as keys in dictionaries.

An alternative is to use `tuple(kwargs.items())` as this part of the key in the `cache` dictionary, and translate back into dictionary as needed. This is only possible if you have no dictionaries (or other mutable objects) referenced within your `kwargs` dictionary.

I have not personally used it, but `frozendict` appears to convert dictionaries to immutable types.

Here is an example that illustrates the types of incoming positional arguments and keyword arguments.

```
def f(*args,**kwargs):
  print(type(args),type(kwargs))
```

Output of `f(1,2,3)` is

```
<class 'tuple'> <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Thanks @jpf. Understood what you suggested. And it works. Great.