# Get inner nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hashtable

I am trying to get arbitrary values from nested dictionaries, but getting an error.
My approach works for one level `dict` like this:

```
    table = [
        {
            "A": 157,
            "B": 221,
            "C": 330,
            "D": 380
        },
        {
            "A": 510,
            "B": 547,
            "C": 660,
            "D": 780
        },
        {
            "A": 791,
            "B": 1111,
            "C": 1200,
            "D": 3000
        },
        ]

    from operator import itemgetter
    val = 525
    for dv in table:
        column_B = max(val, dv['B'])
        if val <= dv['B']:
            column_A = (dv['A'])
            column_C = dv['C']
            pct = dv['D']
            break
```

But if I nest the dicts, I get an error.

```
    table = [
        "inner":{
        
            {   "A": 157,
                "B": 221,
                "C": 330,
                "D": 380
            },
            {
                "A": 510,
                "B": 547,
                "C": 660,
                "D": 780
            },
            {
                "A": 791,
                "B": 1111,
                "C": 1200,
                "D": 3000
            },
        }

    ]
```

I get an error with above nested dict. I tried slicing, even tried reduced function but could not make it work up this point. What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: Can you please post the error message also?

Comment: The second is not a valid data structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` denotes a list. `{}` denotes a dictionary. It looks like you've gotten the two partially mixed up. In order for `table` to make sense, `table` should be a dictionary, and `"inner"` should be a list.

```
# This has a key, therefore it's a dict.
table = {
    # This has no keys, so it's a list.
    "inner": [
    
        {   "A": 157,
            "B": 221,
            "C": 330,
            "D": 380
        },
        {
            "A": 510,
            "B": 547,
            "C": 660,
            "D": 780
        },
        {
            "A": 791,
            "B": 1111,
            "C": 1200,
            "D": 3000
        },
    ]

}
```