# Counter throws error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python

I want to eliminate repeated elements from list and return number of time element is repeated

Even though i'm using list but in json format Counter throws error

if dict inside list cannot be used here please let me know any fast alternative (because len(all_response) would be in 6 digit )

here is my code:

```
from collections import Counter
all_response = [
          {
           "stock_id": 315,
            "product_id": 315
        },
        {
           "stock_id": 315,
            "product_id": 315
        },
        {
            "stock_id": 1,
            "product_id": 1
        },
        {
            "stock_id": 2,
            "product_id": 2
        },
        {
            "stock_id": 2,
            "product_id": 2
        },
        {
            "stock_id": 6,
            "product_id": 6
        }]
stock_ids = []
d = Counter(all_response)
for i in all_response:
    if i['stock_id'] not in stock_ids:
        stock_ids.append({'stock_id':i['stock_id']})
        stock_ids.append({'product_count': d[i['stock_id']]})
print(stock_ids)
```

Expected Output:

```
[
          {
           "stock_id": 315,
            "product_count": 2
        },{
            "stock_id": 1,
            "product_count": 1
        },
        {
            "stock_id": 2,
            "product_count": 2
        },
        {
            "stock_id": 6,
            "product_count": 1
        }]
```

Comment: You cannot have a mutable data type like a dictionary or list as a key. So, you get an error

Comment: What's the definition of a repeated element here? Can you post your expected outcome of the above code (if it was running).

Comment: I have added Expected Output Hope its Understandable..    Note how repeated element get removed and "product_count" key

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
original_list = [{'stock_id': 315, 'product_id': 315}, {'stock_id': 1, 'product_id': 1}, {'stock_id': 2, 'product_id': 2}, {'stock_id': 2, 'product_id': 2}, {'stock_id': 6, 'product_id': 6}]

intermediate_result = {}
for i in original_list:
  if i["stock_id"] in intermediate_result.keys():
    intermediate_result[i["stock_id"]] = intermediate_result[i["stock_id"]]+1
  else:
    intermediate_result[i["stock_id"]] = 1

result = []
for k,v in intermediate_result.items():
  result.append({"stock_id": k, "count": v})

print(result)
```

```
[{'stock_id': 315, 'count': 1}, {'stock_id': 1, 'count': 1}, {'stock_id': 2, 'count': 2}, {'stock_id': 6, 'count': 1}]
```

About your code:

```
stock_ids = []
d = Counter(all_response)
for i in all_response:
  # here is not okay. stock_ids is list of dictionaries
  # so you comparing integer id with one of dictionaries
  if i['stock_id'] not in stock_ids:
    # here is half okay (you appending only id key, without count key)
    stock_ids.append({'stock_id':i['stock_id']})
    # here is not okay, because you trying to append new element to list
    # you should append only once if you want only one dictionary element
    stock_ids.append({'product_count': d[i['stock_id']]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the error message says, `Counter` can't accept a `dict` as input. But you can create a list of items from the key you are interested in.

```
d = Counter(x['stock_id'] for x in all_response)
stock_ids = [{'product_id': x, 'product_count': d[x]} for x in d]
```