# TypeError("unhashable type: 'dict'")

Tags: python, json

I am trying to pass a data back to a URL fetch request. We are using Python 3.x

```
            user_type_data = {'user_type': 'admin', 
                'user_name': 'myname', 
                'user_check_flag': 'yes'}

            return_data = json.dumps({                    
                l_user_type_data            : user_type_data 
            },default = date_handler)

            return return_data
```

When we do this for a dict I am getting the following error - TypeError("unhashable type: 'dict'"). According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict), it states that we cannot use a dict that is not hashabale - but how do we do this?

How do we fix this?

Comment: To be clear, you want to use a dict as a key in another dict, rather than nesting two dicts?

Comment: What is ```l_user_type_data```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A valid dictionary key string should be enveloped by quotes or double quotes.

```
a_dict = {'key': 'value'}  # Valid
b_dict = {"key": "value"}  # Valid
```

Or if you wish to assign string that was stored in a variable to be the dictionary key, you can do this instead:

```
st = "key"
a_dict = dict()
a_dict[st] = 'value'
```

Since `json_dumps` requires a valid python dictionary, you may need to rearrange your code.

If the `l_user_type_data` is a variable contains a string, you should do:

```
temp_dict = dict()
temp_dict[l_user_type_data] = user_type_data
result = json.dumps(temp_dict, default = date_handler)
```

Otherwise, if `l_user_type_data` is a string for the key, just simply enclose that with either single quote or double quotes.

```
return_data = json.dumps({                    
                "l_user_type_data" : user_type_data 
            },default = date_handler)
```