# I would like to get the dictionary a using the dictionary b

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to get the dictionary a using the dictionary b but it gives me an error.

My code :

```
a = {"c":"d"}
b = {{"a":"b"}:a}
print(b[{"a":"b"}])
```

My error :

```
File main.py in line 2
print(b[{"a":"b"}])
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Comment: You simply cannot use a dict as a dictionary key - it has to be something hashable, which generally implies being immutable.  Ints, strings, tuples are the usual choices.

Comment: I am surprised the second line works. Or are you not showing the actual code causing the error since the error refers to line 2 which is actually line 3?!

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14535730/12162258) a question about what "hashable" means in python for your perusal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13264511/typeerror-unhashable-type-dict)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use other dictionary as a key, u can only store a dictionary as a value!

example:

```
a = {
    "key": {"key":"value"}
}
```