# Python: Tell if the argument passed to a function is a constant or is a variable

Tags: python, function, variables, arguments, constants

I want to create a function that would behave differently depending on how the input is passed to it.

For example:

```py
def my_func(a):
   if is_constant_input(a): # Does something like this conditional exist?
      print(f"A constant input {a} was passed")
   else:
      print(f"A variable input {a} was passed")
```

then I call the function in two ways.

First way:

```py
val = [1, 2, 3]
my_func(val) # A variable input [1, 2, 3] was passed.
```

Second way:

```py
my_func([1, 2, 3]) # A constant input [1, 2, 3] was passed.
```

I want to know if there's a way to implement that `is_constant_input()` conditional?

EDIT: fixed the example by using an mutable argument (e.g., a `list`)

Comment: What's the usecase of this requirement?

Comment: sounds like a XY problem

Comment: Nope, not possible. (In any feasible/sane way).

Comment: The same object (`42` in this case) is passed in both cases, the fact that in one case a reference points to it is not visible by the function.

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking that 'constant' is equivalent to immutable?

Comment: @Julien the same object is passed only because small integers are cached, that's a special case.

Comment: @timgeb wouldn't it be the case with any object?

Comment: This isn't something that gets represented in Python's data model: variables are just names associated with values, and `a` just gets bound to a value, with no indication of whether the *source* used a literal or another variable (or more complicated expression) to provide that value. If you really need this for some reason, you would have to use something like the `inspect` module to examine the actual source code.

Comment: @Julien no, consider `def my_func(a): a.append(1)` and call it with `my_func(val)`, where `val` is a list `[1, 2, 3]`. Then call it with `my_func([1, 2, 3])` directly to see the difference. (In the first case, `val` is mutated.)

Comment: @timgeb not the point I was making, but yeah my wording is ambiguous. I mean same object value, not same object id.

Comment: I have a bad example. My specific use-case is more related to mutable arguments (e..g, a `list`). I'll update the example.

Comment: @Julien yes that's correct.

Comment: @RehanRajput lists are not an example of immutable objects

Comment: and the answer is still no :)

Comment: but I'm curious why do you want to do this?

Comment: Very good discussion from 10+ years ago but still valid:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374006/check-for-mutability-in-python