# Is there an ABC (or other way to test) for a mutable collection?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, abc

In Python, there is an ABC for collections that matches all builtin container classes:

```
>>> isinstance(list(), collections.abc.Collection)
True
>>> isinstance(set(), collections.abc.Collection)
True
>>> isinstance(dict(), collections.abc.Collection)
True
```

However, it also matches immutable objects that happen to be sized and iterable:

```
>>> isinstance(str(), collections.abc.Collection)
True
>>> isinstance(bytes(), collections.abc.Collection)
True
```

Is there a good way to test for the first, but not the second group?

I have considered also testing for `collections.abc.Hashable` (any hashable object is non-mutable and is thus not a "container" in a normal sense), but this feels hacky and I'm not sure if this is a semantically correct solution.

I need this because I'm writing a metaprogramming hook that will transform function argument and class field defaults into factories. I need a way to match all classes that will normally result in ["footguns"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761) when used as default arguments/default field values.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4374362/22505347